# How can I create a class in Java, with fields based on a text file with field names?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, plugins

For example, I have a text file that contains list fields

```
 ID             bigint       "This is comment"
 ID_SH          int       "This is comment"
 MARK_BY_TEXT   VARCHAR       "This is comment"
....
```

The list contains  many dozens of the fields. I am need to create Entity with annotations, comments and etc. This is to generate with annotation Hiberante.

can there is a plugin for this purpose or somethigs ?

Comment: If it's a one-off thing just do it manually. If it's a runtime thing, then ask yourself how that it supposed to work in a statically typed language combined with a strong schemaed RDBMS...

Comment: I every day write Entity with large fields. The manager for work with tables of database make sql code when I am watching table. This code have names fields and comments. I point a plugin this file (it ill been into text format) and then I set settting . I got genererated  a class with annootations, types and comments

Comment: This might be helpful https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-97873#focus=streamItem-27-2901987-0-0

Answer (score 1):

you can use "Codota" or "Builder Generator" in intelliJ plugins.

Comment: Builder Generator : i installed but where's setting that parse txt-file with  fields names of a  table and create a class-entity  ?

Comment: Or for plugin Codota, please to show an example, how to create the task that i have described early.

Answer (score 0):

You have to create manually the fields in the class with java datatype and sql data type. You can check the below link.

http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Database-SQL-JDBC/StandardSQLDataTypeswithTheirJavaEquivalents.htm

If you want, you can automate it by creating a mapping between java and sql data type.

Comment: the mapping fields  :  It is to made "Hibetnate"  that was developed according the pattern "ORM".  I asked other question.